# SQL: Consolidate Calculation with Function/Procedure?

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2008, procedure

I have a block of code to adjust the date for my tables.

```
    dateadd(hh,
case
    when
        month(planned_start)=1 or
        month(planned_start)=2 or
        month(planned_start)=11 or
        month(planned_start)=12 then -5
    when
        month(planned_start)=3 then
            case
                when datepart(hh,planned_start)<6 then -5
            else -4
            end
    else -4
end
,planned_start)
```

Basically, I have to adjust my dates for a time difference, but I need to adjust the date in multiple spots in my SQL.  Right now, I just have this block of code repeated about 8 times.

Is there a way to make this into a function or procedure so I can just send 'planned_start' to the function, run the calculation, and return the '-4 or -5' needed to adjust the dates?

Note:  I don't believe I can just use a variable, since 'planned_start' and the hour offset could be different per row of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The 'About' says, "Microsoft SQLServer2008."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your query

```
SELECT Dateadd(hh, CASE
                     WHEN Month(planned_start) IN ( 1, 2, 11, 12 )
                           OR ( Datepart(hh, planned_start) < 6
                                AND Month(planned_start) = 3 ) THEN -5
                     WHEN Month(planned_start) = 3
                          AND Datepart(hh, planned_start) >= 6 THEN -4
                     ELSE -4
                   END, planned_start)
```

and yes you can create a `function` and use it your query instead of repeating the big chunk of code

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Dateadjust (@DATE DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @result DATETIME; -- previously it was int 

      SELECT @result = Dateadd(hh, CASE
                                     WHEN Month(@DATE) IN ( 1, 2, 11, 12 )
                                           OR ( Datepart(hh, @DATE) < 6
                                                AND Month(@DATE) = 3 ) THEN -5
                                     WHEN Month(@DATE) = 3
                                          AND Datepart(hh, @DATE) >= 6 THEN -4
                                     ELSE -4
                                   END, @DATE)

      RETURN( @result );
  END;

GO
```

To use it in `SELECT` statement

```
select planned_start,dbo.Dateadjust(planned_start)
From yourtable
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  However, I'm getting a couple errors.  "Implicit conversion from datetime to INT not allowed, use CONVERT."  and "Cannot find user-defined function dbo.DateAdjust."  Any ideas?  Thanks.    Oh, I adjusted some things and received:  "CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'SM.'"  Does that mean I can't use functions at all?

Comment: @DonTrembly - Yeah there was a mistake in function `@result`  datatype. Please alter the function with new code

Comment: Ok, yea, that worked great.  Now I get the error:  "CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'SM.'" Does that mean I can't use functions at all?

Comment: @DonTrembly - The login you are using to connect the database does not have permission to create function. Request your DBA to create this function or use a login which has permission to create function

Comment: Ok, awesome.  Thanks very much.  This is definitely my selected answer.